# Bounding a sequence defined recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers and $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Let $y_0 := x_n$ and 
$$
 y_k := (\alpha \,y_{k-1} + 1-\alpha) x_{n-k}
$$
for $k=1,2,\dots,n-1$.

Is it possible to give a sharp bound on $y_{n-1}$ based on say $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i$?

Comment: Just checking, is the parenthesis in the question intended, or is it supposed to be just $(1-\alpha)$?

Comment: Are we assuming $\alpha >0$?  If not, we must contend with oscillations.

Comment: @Calvin: The parentheses are intended. We take a convex combination of $y_{k-1}$ and $1$ and then multiply the result with $x_{n-k}$.

Comment: @Walker, yes $\alpha > 0$, I have added it to the assumptions.

Comment: I think in order to obtain a positive answer you have be more specific. You are considering a special case of a [first-order non-homogeneous recurrence relation with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients). Its solution should have not so complicated form, but I expect that we have to impose rather strong restrictions on the sequence $\{x_n\}$ to provide a bound for $y_{n-1}$. For instance, it crucially depends on the value of $x_1$. Also, do you need a lower or an upper bound?